# If $f\in L^p(T)$, then there exists $g\in L^p(T)$ such that $\hat{f}(n)=\hat{g}(n)$ for every $n\geq 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

If p>1, $f\in L^p(T)$, then there exists $g\in L^p(T)$ such that $\hat{f}(n)=\hat{g}(n)$ for every $n\geq 0$ and $\hat{g}(n)=0$ otherwise. I have not been able to come up with any ideas for this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This is false for $p=1$ and $p=\infty$. It's true for $1<p<\infty$, but not at all trivial; if this is a homework problem there must be some related result that's been covered...

Comment: We could probably use more information. What kind of number is $n$? Is $T$ the unit circle? Is the hat notation the Fourier transform?

Comment: I am sorry p>1 in this case. T is the unit circle and n are integers, both positive and negative

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich we can use the fact that if $(\psi f)(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int \frac {e^{it}+z}{e^{it}-z}f(e^{it})dt$ then $\psi f\in H^p$

Comment: @Not_a_topologist Yes, that's one of the possible previous results that gives the theorem more or less immediately. (If it's not clear what $\psi$ has to do with Fourier coefficients, start with the power series for $1/(e^{it}-z)$; that's essentially the sum of a geometric series...)

Comment: $\psi f\in H^p$ is analytic so how about its series coefficients for n < 0 and as $\psi f\in H^p$ consider $g = \lim_{r \to 1} \psi f\in$